# Somar itens de uma categoria Kendo Chart

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, telerik

Tenho um array com o percentual de cada item do gráfico, semelhantemente ao data. Estou tentando montar o template, conforme o código `template: "#= series.abbr #: #= value # (#= series.percent #)`. Segue abaixo o código:

```
 $("#chart").kendoChart({
                title: {
                    text: "Gross domestic product growth /GDP annual %/"
                },
                legend: {
                    position: "bottom"
                },
                                seriesDefaults: {
                  labels: {
                      template: "#= series.abbr #: #= value # (#= series.percent #)",
                      position: "outsideEnd",
                      visible: true,
                      background: "transparent"
                  },
                    type: "column"
                },
                series: [{
                    abbr: "IND",
                    name: "India",
                    data: [3.907, 7.943, 7.848],
                        percent: [3.2, 7.3, 7.1]
                }, {
                    abbr: "RF",
                    name: "Russian Federation",
                    data: [4.743, 7.295, 7.175],
                    percent: [3.6, 7.4, 7.9]
                },{
                    abbr: "WRD",
                    name: "World",
                    data: [1.988, 2.733, 3.994],
                    percent: [1.3, 2.7, 3.7]
                }],
                valueAxis: {
                    labels: {
                        format: "{0}%"
                    },
                    line: {
                        visible: true
                    },
                    axisCrossingValue: 0
                },
                categoryAxis: {
                    categories: [2009, 2010, 2011],
                    line: {
                        visible: true
                    },
                    labels: {
                        padding: {top: 1}
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    visible: true,
                    format: "{0}%",
                    template: "#= series.name #: #= value # : #= series.total #"
                }
            });
```

Infelizmente, consigo pegar apenas o `series.percent`, pegando assim a linha toda. Ao gerar o gráfico, fica assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de alguma forma somar ou então pegar a porcentagem de cada item do gráfico dentro do array percent e aplicar ao gráfico, como o `data` (usando o `value` dentro do `template`). Sendo assim, o gráfico teria essa forma:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]